# How to get meta data information of a sql query

Tags: java, jdbc, postgresql-9.1

I am using postgres 9.1 and java code for jdbc.

I may use a `order by` clause in my `sql query string`

I just want to get the `meta data` information of the query to find whether the query has `order by` clause or not. If it has then how many fields has been specified in the `order by clause`.

`Ex:`
`order by age`
`order by age, name`
`order by age asc, name desc`

In these example I just want to retrieve the number of parameters that are specified in the order by clause and their column names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your are getting your query as string you could simply parse it.

i.e. To figure out that ORDER BY is there

```
"SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY SomeColumn".toLowerCase().indexOf("order by") // if it's return -1 query does not contains order by section otherwise it returns start index for first occurence "ORDER BY" in given string
```

For more complex searching in string you may need to use [RegExp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by breaking an SQL query into part and then reassigning. 
Like

```
String sql="SELECT NAME,COMPANY,FNAME,AGE FROM COMP_DATA JOIN PERSONAL_DATA WHERE (1=1) AND FNAME='Vaibs' ORDER BY AGE";
```

While writing in JAVA do as below.
Break Whole query into String parts and recombine it like this.

```
String strSQL = "SELECT " + "NAME"+",COMPANY"+",FNAME"+",AGE" + "FROM "
        + getTableName1();  //getTableName1() return tablename

strSQL+="JOIN "+ getTable2()+"";//getTable2() return tablename as well

String strWhere = " WHERE (1=1) " + " and FNAME='" + fname+ "';


String orderBySQL = " Order by " + i_will_return_string_to_order_by();

 //return  AGE in our case

String FinalString= strSQL +strWhere +orderBySQL ;
```

**SOP order by to get what you want.
Hope that helped.**

Comment: The query string will come from some other source like xml or some database.